# ChartJS: Limit Y Axis to cut outlimit values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS to show graph with some out of my limits values making the chart less usable, example:
[image]

I want to cut the Y axis to show more exact data, something like this:
[image]

I tried with this:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: lineData,
  options: lineOptions,
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      ticks: {
        min: 0,
        max: 600
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

But this not Works.
Anysuggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scales should be placed inside options in the json like in this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/52afmcej/

```
options: {
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
             min: 0,
             max: 600,      
             }
          }]
      }
   }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Updated to Chart.js **v3.2.0**

In latest version of Chart.js **v3.xx** (which is not backwards compatible with **v2.xx**) you would have to place the `min: 0` and `max: 600` **outside** the ticks object:

```
options: {
   scales: {
      y: {
         min: 0,
         max: 600,
         ticks: {
            // min max not inside here anymore
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Source: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#step-size